# Задача шашку в дамки алгоритм

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Как посчитать сколькими способами шашка может пройти в дамки на шахматной доске 8х8? (если известно начальное расположение шашки) Решение на эту задачу в интернете есть, а вот именно саму логику как это считается не могу.

UPD: На доске всего одна шашка. В качестве входных данных нужно задать текущее положение шашки на доске, а программа должна высчитать возможное количество путей.

Comment: Зависит от того, какие ходы допустимы, наличия других шашек, в т.ч. других цветов, от того, что есть "пройти в дамки"... от формы доски, в конце концов.

Comment: квадратная доска 8х8. 1 Шашка. Если, например, шашка находится в самом низу в самой первой клетке, то сколько путей возможно?

Comment: *в самом низу в самой первой клетке, то сколько путей возможно?* Ты когда-нить шашечную доску видел? нет? найди в Инете фотографию и рассмотри. Видишь, углы - разные?

Comment: Шашки ходят только по чёрным полям. Если я говорю в самом углу внизу, то я имею ввиду левый нижний угол. Потому что правый нижний угол никак не может быть т.к он белый

Comment: Объяснение алгоритма: https://znanija.com/task/37811540